# How do I filter a data.frame in R by categorical variable?

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe

Just learning R.

Given a `data.frame` in R with two columns, one numeric and one categorical, how do I extract a portion of the `data.frame` for usage?

```
str(ex0331)
'data.frame':   36 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Iron      : num  0.71 1.66 2.01 2.16 2.42 ...
$ Supplement: Factor w/ 2 levels "Fe3","Fe4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Basically, I need to be able to operate on the two factors separately; i.e. I need the ability to individually determine length/mean/sd/etc of the Iron retention rate by `Supplement` type (`Fe3` or `Fe4`).

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

I'm aware of the `by()` command. For example, the following gets some of what I need:

```
by(ex0331, ex0331$Supplement, summary)
ex0331$Supplement: Fe3
     Iron       Supplement
Min.   :0.710   Fe3:18    
1st Qu.:2.420   Fe4: 0    
Median :3.475             
Mean   :3.699             
3rd Qu.:4.472             
Max.   :8.240             
------------------------------------------------------------ 
ex0331$Supplement: Fe4
     Iron        Supplement
Min.   : 2.200   Fe3: 0    
1st Qu.: 3.892   Fe4:18    
Median : 5.750             
Mean   : 5.937             
3rd Qu.: 6.970             
Max.   :12.450
```

But I need more flexibility. I need to apply `axis` commands, for example, or `log()` functions by group. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this; I just don't see it. All of the `data.frame` manipulation documentation I've seen is for numerical rather than categorical variables.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "`log()` functions by group" -- `log()` is not a summarizing function, whereas `mean()`, `sd()` are summarizing functions (i.e. they produce one result for a vector input). For functions like `log()` you are probably simply looking to transform the `Iron` variable using a log function? Or perhaps you want to take the `mean()` of the `log(Iron)` quantities? If you are simply looking for another column `LogIron`, then there's no need to group by `Supplement` -- you just convert each entry in the `Iron` column to `Log(Iron)`... see my edit below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a subset of your data by indexing or using `subset`:

```
ex0331 <- data.frame( iron=rnorm(36), supplement=c("Fe3","Fe4"))

subset(ex0331, supplement=="Fe3")
subset(ex0331, supplement=="Fe4")

ex0331[ex0331$supplement=="Fe3",]
```

Or at once with `split`, resulting in a list:

```
split(ex0331,ex0331$supplement)
```

Another thing you can do is use `tapply` to split by a factor and then perform a function:

```
tapply(ex0331$iron,ex0331$supplement,mean)
        Fe3         Fe4 
-0.15443861 -0.01308835
```

The `plyr` package can also be used, which has loads of useful functions. For example:

```
library(plyr)
daply(ex0331,.(supplement),function(x)mean(x[1]))
        Fe3         Fe4 
-0.15443861 -0.01308835
```

## Edit

In response to edited question, you could get the log of iron per supplement with:

```
ex0331 <- data.frame( iron=abs(rnorm(36)), supplement=c("Fe3","Fe4"))

tapply(ex0331$iron,ex0331$supplement,log)
```

Or with `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
dlply(ex0331,.(supplement),function(x)log(x$iron))
```

Both returned in a list. I'm sure  there is an easier way then the wrapper function in the plyr example though.

Comment: Outstanding, thanks! Question: what is the "iron=rnorm(36)" doing in the original subset?

Comment: Thats just to simulate some data to play with.

Comment: Ah, ok. I've already got the data in that data.frame. So I assume what I actually want is newdata <- data.frame( ex0331, supplement=c("Fe3","Fe4")). Is that right?

Comment: It was meant to simulate the dataset you already have: `ex0331`, which has a `iron` column containing numbers and a factor column `supplement`. So you shouldn't need to create a new data.frame

Comment: @SachaEpskamp Is there any method to see if there's any variable to be factored in a data frame without us manually factoring them? How can we know if there are any categorical variables that should be encoded as factors in a data.frame ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using `ddply` function from the `plyr` package, detailed doc is online:

```
> require(plyr)
> ddply( ex0331, .(Supplement), summarise, 
         mean = mean(Iron), 
         sd = sd(Iron), 
         len = length(Iron))

  Supplement       mean        sd len
1        Fe3 -0.3749169 0.2827360   4
2        Fe4  0.1953116 0.7128129   6
```

**Update**.
To add a `LogIron` column where each entry is the `log()` of the `Iron` value, you would simply use `transform`:

```
> transform(ex0331, LogIron = log(Iron))

         Iron Supplement     LogIron
1  0.07185141        Fe3 -2.63315498
2  1.10367297        Fe3  0.09864368
3  0.48592428        Fe3 -0.72170246
4  0.20286918        Fe3 -1.59519393
5  0.80830682        Fe4 -0.21281357
```

Or, to create a summary that is the "mean of the log Iron values, per Supplement", you would do:

```
> ddply( ex0331, .(Supplement), summarise, meanLog = mean(log(Iron)))
  Supplement    meanLog
1        Fe3 -1.0062304
2        Fe4  0.2791507
```